# Why does power loss in pure metal caused by temperature is calculated base on $P=I^2R$ but not $\frac{U^2}{R}$

Tags: electrostatics, power

$$P=I^2R=\frac{U^2}{R}$$

The metal's resistivity is temperature dependent, neglect the change in size by temperature. The power loss of a pure metal when it drop form temperature $T_1$ to $T_2$ is

$$\frac{P_2-P_1}{P1} = \frac{R_2-R_1}{R_1} or \frac{\frac{1}{R_2}-\frac{1}{R_1}}{\frac{1}{R_1}}$$
$$\frac{\frac{1}{R_2}-\frac{1}{R_1}}{\frac{1}{R_1}}=\frac{R_1-R_2}{R_2}$$

why there's difference between using $I^2R$ and $\frac{U^2}{R}$ to calculate the power loss. I used $\frac{U^2}{R}$ but my text book use $I^2R$. What is the reason $\frac{U^2}{R}$ is not the right choice

Answer (score 0):

As your first equation is correct, there is no difference in using $RI^2$ or $U^2/R$ to calculate the power $P = U \cdot I$. My best guess to their choise is that the example gives you the resistance and the current, so this is the simplest way to calculate the power since you don't have to calculate the voltage in a middle step. Furthermore, it is often more practical to calculate the power that way, since it is easier to know the resistance of a component and the current of your circuit, since the current in a serial configuration is the same everywhere, the voltage drop of each part differs.

I am not sure what you want to express with your second point. The power that is produced in a part with resistance $R$ is $P = RI^2$, and the energy produced here dissipates as heat. I have never heard anyone speak of a "power loss" when reducing the temperature or resistance of a component. What does your *or* mean?

Comment: No, the question in my book is about resistivity $\rho$ temperature dependency. As T increase $\rho$ increase therefore R increase as well as when T decrease. So when T is changed, R is changed. Power loss is how much power is lost when changing the temperature compared with initial temperature

Comment: So $\rho$ increases when $T$ increases as well as when $T$ decreases? Power *loss* may be misleading, better talk in terms of in- or decrease.